# REST call returning 'No parameters set'

Tags: php, web-services, rest, curl

I'm trying to make a rest call to a API using curl. This is my current code:

```
$service_url = '...';

    $curl = curl_init($service_url);
    $curl_post_data = array(
            'nome' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'age' => $this->age
    );

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

    var_dump( $curl_response );
```

I know that the array containing the name, email and age have information because I echoed them.

The problem is when I var_dump the $curl response I get the following message:

```
{"status":"NOK","errorCode":-1,"errorMessage":"No Parameters sent"}
```

Any idea on what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$service_url = '...';

$curl = curl_init($service_url);
$curl_post_data = array(
        'nome' => $this->name,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'age' => $this->age
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($curl_post_data));  // using http_query_builder
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // for receiving  response from server

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

var_dump( $curl_response );
```

The option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` will let curl_exec() return the response (to optional further parsing.